# Unregister from PushKit notifications using unregisterForRemoteNotifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit

In our application we're using `PushKit` to receive `VoIP` notifications.

When the user logs out we don't want to receive any `PushKit` notifications. We unregister the device token on our server when the users logs out but if for instance the user doesn't have internet connection when they log out then the request that unregisters the device token will fail (and we allow the user to logout regardless).

That's why we're calling `unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` when the users logs out (along with unregistering from the server).

However we've noticed that if the request that unregisters the token from the server failed, even if we called `unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` (and we've confirmed that `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` returns `false`) we still receive the `PushKit` notification.

We do check when we receive the notification if the user is logged in, and if not we silently discard the notification.

However, we're concerned that by discarding these notifications we're going to experience the following iOS 13+ crash `Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback.`

What would be the recommended way to tell the system to discard these notifications or to not forward these notifications to our application at all?

Thank you,
Cosmin

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
func stopVoIPPush() {
    voipRegistry?.desiredPushTypes = []
    voipRegistry?.delegate = nil
   // voipRegistry = nil
}
```

Should unregister your PushKit. I used this and it is working.